# JINI vs WCF comparison / articles

Tags: wcf, jini

Does anyone know where I can find a good JINI vs WCF comparison / article? I've googled a lot and seriously can't find anything..

Best regards,

MF.

Comment: Did you mean "jni"? If so, then I don't think the two are comparable.

Comment: I meant JINI, i wrote jini on the tags textbox but apparently it selected jni and I didn't notice until now. Fixed it :) And JINI and WCF should be comparable..both are used for service layers, both support transactions accross services, both support discovery,etc. I'm writing a comparison between how both technologies handle transactions but I can't seem to find similar articles on the web..